# Data erase in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new in code with Javascript and I have a problem with an array I need to create.

```
var tabLine = new Array();
var tabCol = new Array();
var tabComplet = new Array();
var fso, f1, ts, s, cl, ln;
var ForReading = 1;
var i = 0;

function ReadFiles() {
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
// Read the contents of the file.
ts = fso.OpenTextFile("PathToAFile\TextFile.txt", ForReading);
s = ts.ReadAll();
tabLine = s.split('\n');
cl = tabLine.length;
ts.Close();
for (i = 0; i <tabLine.length; i++) {
    var tabCol = tabLine[i].split("\t");
    for (j=0;j<tabCol.length;j++) {
        tabComplet[i,j] = tabCol[j];
        alert(tabComplet[i,j]);
    }
 }
 alert(tabComplet[10,5]);
 alert(tabComplet[3,5]);
}

ReadFiles();
```

The file I need to read is a text file; It have many line and each line have information separate by tabulation. 
This function read the text file and convert it into an array in two dimensions. 
I had some alert to check the contain of my array. 
The first alert give me the result I want (it display the content of the array witch is different for each element in the array)but the two other give me the same result. I check with another alert and, in the for boucle, these two element are different. 
I make more test and all happen like if my array only have the same line copy/paste.

Thanks in advance for all information that can help me.

Here is an example of file I use :
http://www.k-upload.fr/afficher-fichier-2017-05-18-1b0cfa685testimport2.txt.html 
Usually there are bigger than this one but for test it's OK.

Comment: It should be `[i][j]` not `[i,j]`

Comment: @Satpal I try to change tabComplet[i,j] by tabComplet[i][j] but when I do this, I have an error when the script read one of the line. And I don't understand why I have an error now. I attach an example of file I use.